# NoSuchElementException while using Scanner object and iterating in a loop

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

I'm currently getting a `NoSuchElementException` when going through my for loop a second time. I was able to loop without issues prior to making some changes to my code. I had to move the user input in the method `setRiskAmount()`, instead of using the same `Scanner` object in this class to read that input. That's when I started getting the error. I know the exception gets thrown when there is nothing to be read from the `Scanner`, I'm just not sure why in this scenario or how to adjust my code.

UPDATE:
If I remove all the code in my `setRiskAmount()` methods, I no longer get the errors, and on my next iteration I'm able to read user input. I was doing it in a different way and it worked perfectly fine. I made the change in order to meet certain requirements for my application.

```
@Override
void setRiskAmount() {
    // Ask for user input using a Scanner

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter risk amount for Property Insurance >> ");
    riskAmount = input.nextFloat();
    input.close();
}
```

> Please enter insurance type (Property, Auto, Travel) or QUIT to exit
>
> > > Property Please enter risk amount for Property Insurance >> 25000
> > >       ****************** PROPERTY INSURANCE The rate is: 0.25 The risk amount is 25000.0 The premium for Property Insurance is: 6250.0
> > >       ****************** Please enter insurance type (Property, Auto, Travel) or QUIT to exit >>  Exception in thread "main"
> > >       java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found   at
> > >       java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)    at
> > >       UseInsurance.main(UseInsurance.java:25)

```
public class UseInsurance {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // The Scanner object will be used for user input
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String t = "";

        // Create the user interface
        // Loop will continue looping until the user decides to exit
        for (int i = 10; i > 0; i++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter insurance type (Property, Auto, Travel) or QUIT to exit >> ");
            t = input.nextLine();
            if (t.equals("Property")) {
                // Create an instance of PropertyInsurance, set the object name and type, ask for user input for risk amount 
                // calculate and add to the total quote. Display the results.

                PropertyInsurance pInsurance = new PropertyInsurance("Property");
                pInsurance.setInsuredObjectName();
                pInsurance.setRiskAmount();
                InsuranceAgentApp.totalPremium += pInsurance.getPremium();
                pInsurance.display();
            } else if (t.equals("Auto")) {
                // Create an instance of AutomobileInsurance, set the object name and type, ask for user input for risk amount 
                // calculate and add to the total quote. Display the results.
                AutomobileInsurance aInsurance = new AutomobileInsurance("Auto");
                aInsurance.setInsuredObjectName();
                aInsurance.setRiskAmount();
                InsuranceAgentApp.totalPremium += aInsurance.getPremium();
                aInsurance.display();
            } else if (t.equals("Travel")) {
                // Create an instance of TravelInsurance, set the object name and type, ask for user input for risk amount 
                // calculate and add to the total quote. Display the results.
                TravelInsurance tInsurance = new TravelInsurance("Travel");
                tInsurance.setInsuredObjectName();
                tInsurance.setRiskAmount();
                InsuranceAgentApp.totalPremium += tInsurance.getPremium();
                tInsurance.display();
            } else if ((t.equals("QUIT")) || (t.equals("quit")) || (t.equals("Quit"))) {
                // Exit the loop upon the user typing QUIT, quit or Quit

                break;
            } else {
                // If none of the above options are selected, display a message
                // and loop again.

                System.out.println("Invalid input");
            }
        }

        // Display the amount of the total quote
        System.out.println("The total quote is " + InsuranceAgentApp.totalPremium);
        // Close the Scanner object
        input.close();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are closing your input after the quote, simply remove that line. Also, I included some code that may work better for you, as it is cleaner and more consolidated. I left comments to explain what I did.

```
        Boolean done = false; //Boolean variable to monitor loop without increments

        // Create the user interface
        // Loop will continue looping until the user decides to exit
        while(!done){
            System.out.println("Please enter insurance type (Property, Auto, Travel) or QUIT to exit >> ");
            t = input.nextLine();
            t = t.toUpperCase();//normalizes the string to all upercase letters
            switch(t){
                case "PROPERTY":
                    //your code
                case "AUTO":
                    //your code
                case "TRAVEL":
                    //your code
                case "QUIT":
                    done = true;//loop wil exit when done is true

                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid Input");
                    }


        }
```

Comment: `t = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();` would suffice. There's no need to split it across two separate lines.

Comment: @Bethany Louise I don't even know why I considered that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `setRiskAmount()`. When you close a `Scanner` reading from `System.in`, it not only closes that particular `Scanner` but also closes `System.in`. This prevents the `Scanner` in your main method from reading any further input from `System.in`.

The solution is to simply remove the line closing this `Scanner`. You should never, ever close a `Scanner` reading from `System.in` if there's any possibility that any input will have to be read from `System.in` later on in your code.

Comment: That did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {
static float riskAmount;
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {  
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        setRiskAmount();
        if(i==9){
            System.out.println("Total Risk Amount is: "+ riskAmount); 
        }
    }   
}
static void setRiskAmount() {
    System.out.print("Please enter risk amount for Property Insurance >> ");
    riskAmount+= input.nextFloat();
} }
```

I do it for you it will work 1000% . Just you need to declare Scanner global.

Comment: You can close Scanner after last action. such as    System.out.println("Total Risk Amount is: "+ riskAmount);
input.close();

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {
static float riskAmount;
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {  
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        setRiskAmount();
        if(i==9){
            System.out.println("Total Risk Amount is: "+ riskAmount);
            input.close();
        }
    }   
}
static void setRiskAmount() {
    System.out.print("Please enter risk amount for Property Insurance >> ");
    riskAmount+= input.nextFloat();
} }
```